# Value of each second td in table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can any one tell me how I can get value of second td of of each row in the table.
below I have mention my code here I'm getting same value of each column.can any one tell me how I can get ..

```
 $('td[headers="TYPE"] input').val()
```

Also I have tried this :

```
$('td[headers="TYPE"] input').each(function(){
                               $(this).html()
                               or 
                           $(this).val()

                      });
```

After that I'm getting `[object Object]`

can any one tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It [works in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/o50vzkjp/) "as is".

Comment: in alert is working fine ..when i am try to display then again i m getting [object object]..can u tell me why this thing happen

Comment: I don't know where you are trying to display it, so I don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small script to do just this actually, for scraping a website's table.

```
var x = [];
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("tr > td:nth-child(2)"), function(z) {
    //z.value etc
    //z is the DOM element
});
```

You may benefit from the CSS selector I used, which grabs every second td in each row. Just manipulate the selector as needed to grab just the inputs, and you have your inputs.

Better yet, push them into an array for easy storage.

```
x.push(z.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below script will give you html of second td of each row.

```
<table id="tbl">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>33</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#tbl td:nth-child(2)" ).each(function(){
        alert( $(this).html() );
    })
})
</script>
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/o7jvgvpL/) is demo.